# Connecting Mongoose to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Below is the code from the Mongoose website to connect mongoose. But I am getting some kind of error.
The error is too long. Here is the error.

```
"connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:824:32)
    at F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:10
    at F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)    
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1225:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:379:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Web development\mong\index.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:824:32)        
    at F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:10
    at F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1225:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:379:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Web development\mong\index.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 338285881,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\Web development\mong\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:302:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        }
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}"
```

Here is the code from the mongoose website. I am hoping to get some help. I dont know what the problem is really. I have tried using different version of mongoose as well. I successfully install mongoose, but when i try to run the code below, it gives the error shown above.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
  console.log('hello there');
});
```

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Your `mongodb` didn't connect?

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: yes iam using windows

Comment: i have added the error in the question now

Answer (score 0):

I've got you. You are running `mongoDB` on `mongodb compass`. For that your machine needs to run a `service`. If you are using windows. `Go to : task manager>services>` scroll down and find the service name `MongoDB`. I believe the current status of `MongoDB` is `stopped`. `right click` on it and `click` `start`. MongoDB service must be in `running status`.
then first try with this simple code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
.then(()=>{
    console.log('connected to database')
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: I just found out that my mongodb was somehow deleted from my system. Reinstalling it now